# Custom resources equivalent to jetty JNDI resource

Tags: glassfish, payara-micro

I have a web application which is until now deployed to a jetty server but now in order to use other JavaEE services I'm shifting to Payara (Glassfish) container. However I can't find how to provide additional JNDI resources as configuration to paraya.
Currently I have some resources like this defined in my jetty's context.xml file:

```
<New id="some_resource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>
        <Ref refid='wac'/>
    </Arg>
    <Arg>resource/path</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.example.some.Class">
            <!-- constructor parameters -->
            <Arg type="java.lang.String">some string</Arg>
            <Arg type="java.lang.Integer">0</Arg>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

this simply calls the custom class constructor with given parameters and puts the result into given `resource/path` address.

Is this possible to be done in payara micro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to create a custom resource that is exposed via JNDI, though GlassFish/Payara support only primitive types by default. For other types you would need to add a custom factory in the server classpath.

Custom resources in Payara/GlassFish are defined in `domain.xml`, in element `custom-resource`. Best way to define a custom resource is either using Admin Console (Resources -> JNDI -> Custom resources) or `asadmin` command.

For a string value "some string" under a JNDI `resource/path`,  the asadmin would look like this:

```
asadmin> create-custom-resource --restype java.lang.String --factoryclass org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory --property value="some string" "resource/path"
```

In Payara Micro, you can either pass `domain.xml` using `--domainConfig` argument, or you can execute the same `asadmin` command from within your application, using [PayaraMicroRuntime.run()](http://payara.github.io/Payara/nucleus_API/payara-modules/payara-micro/target/apidocs/fish/payara/micro/PayaraMicroRuntime.html#run(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)) (documented [here](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/documentation/payara-micro/appendices/operation-methods.html#run-methods))

Comment: so directly calling the constructor of the resource is not possible? and I have to create one factory per resource type.

Comment: You could create a single generic factory for all classes and pass constructor arguments via properties. If you do, it would be also worth to contribute via a pull request. I don't think that Payara/GlassFish contains such factory out of the box.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarification, that would be lot of help. I have to find some time then to write such a proper generic factory maybe by looking at what [jetty has](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/)

Comment: It seems there is already a [generic factory for Java Beans](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/giyvw/index.html). I found out just now by searching the net.

Comment: java beans but not any class. As in beans you need a default parameterless ctor which not an acceptable standard for me.

Comment: I see. Having a factory to create resources using constructor would be nice. As Payara only accepts properties which don't retain order, I recommend to accept a property with a name of a JSON/XML file that contains the definition of the resource. If you publish your code, I'm willing to contribute.